# How does the concept of "fresh pair of eyes" work in graphic design? Can it be expedited somehow?

Tags: design-principles, designers

In almost all my design/illustration making process, when I start it and complete the first draft and review it later, maybe after few hours, there's room for improvement. I can even find silly mistakes in it. Which I can't notice or can't think about improving when I was working on it.

Similarly, if I further leave it for 2-3 days, there's still room for some improvement and silly mistake fixing. And sometimes, I can evaluate it to the extent that I find it not worth finalizing and why it wouldn't work and I work on a new concept.

So when I finalize it, after say 6-7 days, I'm quite satisfied with it and I publish it. I keep checking from time to time. And I like it.

Months later, I find that *this* thing could be improved, I made a mistake here. Why couldn't I notice it at that time.

So you know, this keeps going on. But yes, room for improvement keeps decreasing with time, in most cases.

I understand that you might definitely do a design better after a longer period of time because you have more experience till then. I understand often we find some of designs a bit bad after few years because we learn new things. But still what I'm discussing is more about my *ignorant* eyes.

I just feel if I can *make it fast*, I can think/design/illustrate better in comparatively less time.

**So how does it work and what are some ways to *expedite* (for example alternative ways if any) it somehow?**

Comment: There's no way to expedite anything. The longer you are away, the more you'll want to alter.

Comment: (it wasn't me...)

Comment: @Scott I won't mind it even if it was you, for this question.